# question about the "20 pips challenge"

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange

I am trying to do the "20 pips challenge", where you starts a trading account with small money (here 1000 euros account, but you trade only 2%, i.e 20 $) and where you try to make 20 pips at each trade.

[image: 20 pips challenge]

But one thing I don't understand, on TradingView / paperview account, If I want to buy for 20 $ (see screenshot below) I have to specify 200 000 units and it makes the value of 1 pip equal to 20 $.
So, here, if I earn 20 pips I will earn 20 x 20 = 400 $ ...

[image: tradingview2]

I know there is something clearly wrong in my understanding, but I cannot find what.

Comment: @njzk2 [Please do not answer questions in the comment area.](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/10997)

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica well, I could not see his answer...